# find and replace all html code <td> not working

Tags: jquery, html

why find and replace html code not working? but when i'm test with a string or some text it work. please give me solution. this below i write my sample code and the result code when i want

(#1)My Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getContent = $("table").html();
  var setReplaced = getContent.replace(/\td><td/g, 'td></tr><tr><td');
  $("table").html(setReplaced);
  console.log(setReplaced);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>444</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(#2) I want to Html Like this.

```
<table>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>444</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

please correct my jquery code. and give me a solution.
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in your regular expression.
Did you mean :

```
getContent.replace(/\/td><td/g,'/td></tr><tr><td');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to replace instances of this: `\td><td` but you'd never close a HTML tag with a backslash. `\td>` should be a forward slash instead. Make sure you escape it, too.

```
getContent.replace(/\/td><td/g,'/td></tr><tr><td');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an each loop instead of a regex:

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var $thisTr = $(this),        // get this tr
    $newTr = $('<tr></tr>');    // make a new tr
  
  $newTr.append($thisTr.children().last());    // append the last cell into the new tr
  $thisTr.after($newTr);                       // put the new tr after the current tr
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>444</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var tds = $('table').find('td');
  if ( tds.parent().is( "tr" ) ) {
    tds.unwrap();
  }
  $('table td').wrap('<tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td>111</td><td>222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>333</td><td>444</td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you seem to be really looking for :

- For each non-first `td`
- Insert a new `tr` below the current one
- And move the `td` in the new row

This has the advantage of not modifying the html directly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $("table");
    var cells = $("td:not(:first-child)", table);
    cells.each(function(i, td) {
        var newtr = $("<tr>");
        $(td).parent().after(newtr);
        newtr.append(td);
    });
});
```